# When I add this code to my script Unity crashes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code I am using to generate a map in my RPG game.
Unity does not tell me the error it simply stops responding so I have to force stop the application. I have reviewed all the code and confirmed the settings in Unity, still the same problem occurs.
I am following this tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HT_eUPBJGZw&list=PLX-uZVK_0K_6JEecbu3Y-nVnANJznCzix&index=23

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform map;

    [SerializeField]
    private Texture2D[] mapData;

    [SerializeField]
    private MapElement[] mapElements;

    [SerializeField]
    private Sprite defaultTile;

    private Vector3 WorldStartPos
    {
        get
        {
            return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0));
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GenerateMap();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void GenerateMap()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < mapData.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < mapData[i].width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; x < mapData[i].height; y++)
                {
                    Color c = mapData[i].GetPixel(x, y);

                    MapElement newElement = Array.Find(mapElements, e => e.MyColor == c);

                    if(newElement != null)
                    {
                        float xPos = WorldStartPos.x + (defaultTile.bounds.size.x * x);
                        float yPos = WorldStartPos.y + (defaultTile.bounds.size.y * y);

                        GameObject go = Instantiate(newElement.MyElementPrefab);
                        go.transform.position = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);
                        go.transform.parent = map;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MapElement
{
    [SerializeField]
    private string tileTag;

    [SerializeField]
    private Color color;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject elementPrefab;

    public GameObject MyElementPrefab
    {
        get
        {
            return elementPrefab;
        }
    }

    public Color MyColor 
    {
        get
        {
            return color;
        }
    }
    
    public string MyTileTag {
        get
        {
            return tileTag;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `x` by `y` in `for (int y = 0; x < mapData[i].height; y++)` ... I would close this as off-topic due to **typo based**.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are creating an endless loop with `for (int y = 0; x < mapData[i].height; y++)`